# ASP.NET Core 2.0 - Web API Method Multiple Endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

This is my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SaveRecordController : XivicControllerBase
{
    #region REST Calls
    [HttpPost]
    public SaveRecordResponse Post([FromBody] SaveRecordRequest saveRecordRequest)
    {
        var retVal = new SaveRecordResponse();
        try
        {
            ValidateRequest(saveRecordRequest);

            //Save logic here [...]

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex);
            retVal.Errors.Add(new XivicError(ex.Message));
        }

        return retVal;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

It takes any entity, attempts to save it, and then returns the Id of the entity saved, or a collection of errors. Swashbuckle serves up the Swagger UI like so:

[image]

This works fine, but this is not what I want to expose to 3rd party integrators. I want to create multiple endpoints that are generated dynamically based on the configuration in the system of what Record types (Entities) are exposed externally). So, for example, if client x has an entity called "Job", there would be an action called SaveJob, and this would show up in the Swagger documentation.

If I add a new HttpPost attributes, I can get the new endpoint like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [HttpPost("SaveJob")]
    public SaveRecordResponse Post([FromBody] SaveRecordRequest saveRecordRequest)
    {
    }
```

This does show up in Swagger as I would expect it to, but here comes the rub...

I cannot add attributes to the class SaveRecordController because it is a core type inside our core application assembly. External entities(record types) are defined at runtime. They are not actual types inside the application. So I don't know how to add the endpoints dynamically at runtime. I guess there are some routing options in ASP.NET Core 2.0, but the Swashbuckle documentation explicitly says

> Additionally, if you are using conventional routing (as opposed to
>   attribute routing), any controllers and the actions on those
>   controllers that use conventional routing will not be represented in
>   ApiExplorer, which means Swashbuckle won't be able to find those
>   controllers and generate Swagger documents from them.

So the doco would not get generated properly. I'm stuck. What should I do?